# Android Studio Adb Transfer Protocol Error

Tags: android-studio, adb, permission-denied

I've just started using Android Studio.  I've got an HTC one (m7) running rooted Lollipop.  I'm trying to run the test app I've created on this physical device.  When I go to run it I get "Adb Transfer Protocol Error: Permission Denied". The device shows up in android studio when I go to run the app, and I have verified root access. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I just tried to install a .apk file using the command adb install and I'm getting permission denied.  This is a rooted phone. However, I've always had root access on this phone, and before upgrading to android 5.0 Lollipop I could run this command and instantly install a .apk without having to do adb shell. If this is the problem, how do I tell android studio to run adb shell before trying to install and run the app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, I solved it.  The folder \data\local\tmp did not have full read write execute permissions. Once I did a quick chmod 777 on it Android Studio allowed the installation and run of the app. You can also do this procedure through a file explorer that has root capabilities.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? I'm having the same issue. Are you on linux? Where's the remote path?

Comment: The quick and easy way is to get a file manager on the device that can gain root access, find the \data\local\tmp folder and edit it's properties to give full read write and execute permissions.

Comment: The problem is I don't even have that path. I have a tmp/data folder but there's not much in it.

Comment: What kind of device is it? Do you have root access?

Comment: it's an htc one as well. do.

Comment: But yeah.. once I figure out how to give access to that folder... http://i.imgur.com/rFFrqzP.png

Comment: Try to use adb from cmd prompt. Make sure you have root access. Cd into /data/local and then type chmod 777 tmp

Comment: G D, you the man!

Just to supplement Skye's answer with yours as well:

1) Open terminal on desktop
2) adb shell
3) su
4) cd /data/local
5) chmod 777 tmp

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this in Terminal Emulator. Download the app from this link: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=pl
Of course you need to have root.

Open it and enter:

> su
>
> cd /data/local
>
> chmod 777 tmp

And try run app now